# How to lock specific rows and columns using Excel interop C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to Lock cell range in excel using C# excel interop services but I am unable to do it with following code

```
sheet.Range["A1", "A3"].Locked = true;
```

Comment: sheet.Range["A1", "A3"].Locked = true; sheet.Protect();

Comment: I don't want to make sheet as protected . I want some cells to be protected. If I try this  sheet.Protect(); then entire sheet will be protected which I don't want to

Answer (score 4):

In Excel, you can only effectively lock cells if you lock the worksheet. What you do is:

1. Mark the cell ranges you **don't** want to lock as `Locked = False`
2. Then protect the sheet using `sheet.Protect(UserInterfaceOnly: true)`.