# Block Excel Column using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, com, office-interop, excel-interop

I am developing a windows form application using C#. In this application the user will click a button then the program will copy some columns and rows from the clipboard and past them on a new excel workbook where user can edit the information.
In Excel, I want to block one column only which is the ID such that the user can edit all cells except
that column because this column is system generated. I am not able to get it working. below is my code

```
        DataObject dataObj = null;
        dataGridView1.SelectAll(); // copying data to clipboard
        dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent(); // 

        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.DisplayFullScreen = true;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false);

        // for example block column A only
        xlWorkSheet.Range["A1"].EntireColumn.Style.Locked = true; 
         
        // protect the sheet
        xlWorkSheet.Protect(Type.Missing, true, true, true,
             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, true, Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

My problem is that after running this code  and then unprotecting the sheet, the user can still edit column A. Is there a way I can protect only column A from editing?
**I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version 15. and .Net Framework 4.5.1**

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883664/how-to-lock-specific-rows-and-columns-using-excel-interop-c-sharp .

Comment: yes. the trick was to mark the editable cells as unlocked first before protecting the sheet.  thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this. I don't exactly know where the issue is occurring but this might help.

```cs
        DataObject dataObj = null;
        dataGridView1.SelectAll(); // copying data to clipboard
        dataObj = dataGridView1.GetClipboardContent(); // 

        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlexcel.DisplayFullScreen = true;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range CR = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        CR.Select();
        xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(CR, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false);

        // for example unblock columns B - Z only
        xlWorkSheet.Range("B1", "Z1").EntireColumn.Locked = false;
         
        // protect the sheet
        xlWorkSheet.Protect(Type.Missing, true, true, true,
             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, true, Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
             Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

This is in no way a perfect solution to all your problems. Especially since I don't quite know how many other columns you plan to use, but this code will leave column A locked and then leave B through Z unlocked. If you have any others questions toss them in the comments.

Comment: the issue was that I was assuming that all cells are unlocked and I have to lock only what I want where its the other way around. I had to unlock all editable columns as they are protected. Thanks